# OSGi modules/bundles granularity

Tags: java, osgi

When I first started looking at OSGi I was under the impression that you could just build a JAR and as-long as it had a manifest file, you could deploy it in a OSGi container. I imagined building my modules in a classic way (maven), and maybe use some plugin or something of the sort to write the manifest, I could then have my module that would basically be a standalone application communicating with other modules through OSGi.

Further reading about OSGi, I'm beginning to see more examples of it being used at a more low-level and basically replacing dependency injection and providing cross-cutting concern services like logging. And seems that using things like hibernate or others, is a problem... (or maybe I'm just missing something).

At least for me, I don't really see the point of having a such fine-gained level of modularity   and integration to OSGi, I would much rather have a separate modules, each one of them having its own set of technologies and frameworks, and possibly a web resources and persistence layer. Is this achievable with OSGi? If yes, can you point me in the right direction, examples etc.?

**edit**, added some more details of how I'm trying to use OSGi:

I'm just envisioning the possibility of having a more than one-class module, that might have a more higher-level responsibility.

Like say agenda module. In this case I want to have things like, persistence of the events, add events, list events with filters, etc... 
This agenda might have several internal classes, and might even need a persistence layer. So I would like to use something like Guice to DI those classes, and some JPA to persist my data.

I can understand that some X-cutting concerns like server or logging can have a bundle, but the data model is specific to the agenda bundle. So I think my question was at the end What is and what is not possible to do inside a bundle? And what should and shouldn't be done inside as a general practice?

Thanks!
Mauricio

Answer (score 3):

OSGi is many things to many people, and you can almost pick and choose what parts of it you want to use:

1. Do you have a plain library that doesn't use any other dependencies? Sweet, just put up a minimal MANIFEST.MF listing the public packages, use maven to build your JAR and you're done.
2. Do you have dependencies? Same as (1), you just add the imported packages in your manifest.
3. Do you need to perform some initialization? Write an Activator, and mention it in your manifest.
4. Services? Just put the dependencies and descriptions of those in XML files and add them in the manifest.

And so on - just use the level where you are comfortable.

On the other hand, if you want to do web applications you really need to consider the architectural interplay between OSGi, the libraries you use, your application manager and the servlet/jee/whatever container. At what level will OSGi reside? In a general sense, there are OSGi->container->app, container->OSGi->app and container->app->OSGi solutions, and each has their own idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OSGi without forcing any dependencies on OSGi on the application code. However, since OSGi provides modularity, the middleware (your layers) need to have some knowledge of OSGi. The problem is that in a modular world you want to hide implementation details, that is the whole purpose. However, things like Spring and Hibernate tend to assume the classpath has no boundaries and they run head on into the fences. Fortunately, more and more middleware is becoming prepared for this, I heard Hibernate now has an effort and JPA is also available in OSGi.

Comment: So if I use OSGi-ready frameworks (guice?) I could keep using them inside my bundles?

Comment: Yes, that will work However, my (rather extensive) experience is that when you write very modular code frameworks like Spring, Guice, etc. tends to loose their primary value since the problem becomes so much smaller that these frameworks feel rather overweight. A good bundle is cohesive and then you normally do not need the overhead of these frameworks. However, nothing in the OSGi world prohibits you from adding this weight :-)

Answer (score 1):

Concerning building with maven, you can use the [Maven-Bundle-Plugin](https://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) it helps you to build OSGi bundles without having to write the manifest on your own. All the required meta information will be in your POM.

Dependency injection can be achieved on top of the module layer. One possible solution would be *Declarative Services* which enables you to inject via an XML description or code annotations. It strongly reflects the dynamic nature of OSGi Services (dynamic binding unbinding of services).
The alternative is *Blueprint* which is based upon spring and features a very similar syntax. One key feature is that it can abstract the nature of binding and unbinding of services. If you think about using Spring, use Blueprint.

OSGi only implies how you structure your modules. You get a well defined graph of module interactions (who imports/exports a package? Who exports Services and who uses it?)
therefore you can build an enterprise architecture on top of it by building cohesive bundles for every task.

Answer (score 1):

OSGi is sometimes referred to as a service-oriented architecture for the JVM. Looking at bundles as modular units that provide services helps define the right granularity: you'll usually have API bundles which are just here to provide java packages that define APIs, service bundles that provide implementations of these APIs, and utility/auxiliary bundles that provide the cross-cutting services that you mention.

You can use some dependency injection frameworks on top of OSGi, but from my experience (with Apache Sling and Adobe CQ5) keeping things simple is often better. The OSGi Service Component Runtime and Configuration Admin provide all I need to manage services, dependencies and configurations, especially if you design your system for that from the beginning.

You can find a bit more about our experience with OSGi in designing Adobe CQ5 in my "tales from the OSGi trenches" slides at http://www.slideshare.net/bdelacretaz/tales-from-the-osgi-trenches-2012-short-form-edition - that might help get a better feel for how OSGi is used in  building complex systems.

Comment: Thanks,
I'm just envisioning the possibility of having a more than one-class module, that might have a more higher-level responsibility. Like say agenda module.
In this case I want to have things like, persistence of the events, add events, list events with filters, etc...
This agenda might have several internal classes, and might even need a persistence layer. So I would like to use something like Guice to DI those classes, and some JPA to persist my data.
I can understand that some X-cutting concerns like server can have a  bundle, but the data model is specific to the agenda bundle.

Comment: Note that you can also have internal services in a bundle, using interfaces that are not exported from your bundle and implementations inside the bundle itself - that would work for "local services" used to better modularize your agenda bundle internally, while still using just OSGi's services runtime.